# JDBC SqlLite and Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, sqlite, jdbc, path

i have a problem with my project.
I have a jdbc connection with my sqllite db. But i can`t use a relative path i get always an error.
That are my settings.In the db-layer project. In the class GradingSystemDao.

```
private static final String DB_LINK = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Leumas\\eclipse-workspace\\SA\\db-layer\\db-layer\\d\\test.db";

public GradingSystemDao() {
    // constructor
}

/**
 * Creates the link to the db.
 * 
 * @return The connection of the db.
 */
private Connection getConnection() {
    System.out.println("DBLINK: " + DB_LINK);
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_LINK);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection do not work.");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return c;
}
```

When i use a relative path, i get the the database has been closed error. Same error in this url: 
https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/354

But i can`t fix it, my paths are not very long.

I think it is my project structure, its made with maven.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNOm9.png)

My settings in the pom.xml in logic.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.sf.grasys</groupId>
        <artifactId>db-layer</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My settings in the pom.xml in userinterface.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.sf.grasys</groupId>
        <artifactId>logic</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When i also build a executable jar it doesnt work.
 I hope you can help me.

**Edit**

It is only a little project,so the exception handling is not so important.

```
DBLINK: jdbc:sqlite:..\d\test.db
Connection do not work.
java.sql.SQLException: path to '..\d\test.db': 'C:\Users\Leumas\eclipse-workspace\SA\userinterface\..\d' does not exist
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:192)
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:25)
at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:24)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at  de.sf.grasys.persistence.GradingSystemDao.getConnection(GradingSystemDao.java:49)
at de.sf.grasys.persistence.GradingSystemDao.getAllSchoolClass(GradingSystemDao.java:269)
at de.sf.grasys.service.GradingSystem.loadDataFromDatabase(GradingSystem.java:33)
at de.sf.grasys.ui.Main.start(Main.java:47)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace of the error. Your connection method is a good example of how not to handle exceptions: don't catch exceptions and then allow your code to continue as if nothing happened. If you can't **handle** an exception, then don't catch it (or rethrow it wrapped in a different exception). On a separate not, I don't think your problem has anything to do with Maven.

Comment: I think its a problem with my knowledge of maven. Because I should use an path that fits, but i don;t know how the path should look. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation about the 'current working folder' when running your application is wrong. The absolute path you use is:

```
C:\Users\Leumas\eclipse-workspace\SA\db-layer\db-layer\d\test.db
```

Based on the error, the relative path resolves to

```
C:\Users\Leumas\eclipse-workspace\SA\d\test.db
```

The problem is that the folder `C:\Users\Leumas\eclipse-workspace\SA\d` does not exist.

Make sure your relative path points to an existing folder.

Comment: Yes, i know but the main Problem is that it wont work on the executable jar.

Comment: @ProfessorFritz And that means your expectation of where files are relative to the current working folder is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution only local.

```
private static final String DB_LINK = "jdbc:sqlite:..\\db-layer\\db-layer\\d\\test.db";
```

**Edit**
Ok it works in eclipse, but if I make a executable jar it works not.

```
 C:\Users\Leumas\Desktop>java -jar Benotungssystem.jar
 Connection do not work.
java.sql.SQLException: path to '..\db-layer\db-layer\d\test.db':        'C:\Users\Leumas\Desktop\..\db-layer' does not exist
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:192)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:25)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:24)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at de.sf.grasys.persistence.GradingSystemDao.getConnection(GradingSystemDao.java:48)
    at de.sf.grasys.persistence.GradingSystemDao.getAllSchoolClass(GradingSystemDao.java:268)
    at de.sf.grasys.logic.GradingSystem.loadDataFromDatabase(GradingSystem.java:34)
    at de.sf.grasys.ui.Main.start(Main.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**I want that the path is in the project so that it works on other pcs.**